# Filter list of product in a recyclerview - android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

So I have a list of product in my `recyclerview`. Have a `editText` for search term .

Each time user type something in the `editText` field the list must be filtered .
with live search there is no problem and the process work well .

for better ui experience I created a button(`btn_search`) for the edittext also. But in this case when click on the button the list not filtered and just disappeared .!!!
what is wrong with my code.

Code :

this is function in the adapter that calls datachanged :

```
ListAdapter :

    fun filterList(filtername : List<Model>) {
        this.model = filtername
       notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

activity :

```
    lateinit var editText: EditText
    lateinit var model: ArrayList<Model>
    lateinit var adapter: ListAdapter
    lateinit var button: Button
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

  
    button = findViewById(R.id.btn_search)

    var list = ArrayList<Model>()
    list.add(somedata) ...


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    model = list
    recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, 2)
    adapter = ListAadapter(model)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter


    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_search)


    // this is where call btnsearch but the list not filtered and disappeared
     button.setOnClickListener {
                filter(editText.toString())
        }


    // with this live search there is no issue and list filtered
     
/*
      editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(text: Editable?) {
                filter(text.toString())
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            }


        })*/


// this is the function for filter the list 
   

    fun filter(text: String) {
        val filterNameList = ArrayList<Model>()
        model.filterTo(filterNameList) { model ->
            model.title.contains(text)
        }
        adapter.filterList(filterNameList)
    }
```

So any idea where I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to call editText.getText().toString().
Just calling toString on the editText won't give you it's value.

Comment: thank's body @Dan Baruch . if u would place your comment in the answer place to accept it .

Comment: Glad you got it to work :) and it's ok ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are not getting the `EditText` text, you are casting the `EditText` directly into string in this line

```
button.setOnClickListener {
   filter(editText.toString())
}
```

So, you need to change it to this

```
button.setOnClickListener {
   filter(editText.text.toString())
}
```